# How to type a switch case with multiple payloads type as params?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, types

I have the following scenario:

```
  public async handle(
    handler: WorkflowHandlerOption,
    payload: <how_to_type_it?>,
  ): Promise<StepResponseInterface> {
    switch (handler) {
      case WorkflowHandlerOption.JOB_APPLICATION_ACTIVITY: {
        const {
          entity_id: jobApplicationEntityId,
          status: jobApplicationStatus,
        } = await this.jobApplicationActivityHandler.execute(payload);
        // ...other staff
        break;
      }
      case WorkflowHandlerOption.BILLING_FEE: {
        const { entity_id: billingFeeId, status: billingFeeStatus } =
          await this.billingFeeHandler.execute(payload);
        // ...other staff
        break;
      }
      case WorkflowHandlerOption.DOCUMENT_GENERATION: {
        const { entity_id: documentId, status: documentStatus } =
          await this.documentGenerationHandler.execute(payload);
        // ...other staff
        break;
      }
      case WorkflowHandlerOption.UPDATE_JOB: {
        const { entity_id: jobId, status: jobStatus } =
          await this.jobHandler.execute(payload);
        // ...other staff
        break;
      }
      case WorkflowHandlerOption.DOCUMENT_GENERATION_ACTIVITY: {
        const {
          entity_id: documentActivityId,
          status: documentActivityStatus,
        } = await this.documentGenerationActivityHandler.execute(payload);
        // ...other staff
        break;
      }
      
      default:
        throw new BadRequestException('Handler not found');
    }

    // ...other staff
  }
```

I have many handlers which are getting completely different payloads, how should I type the payload param?

Imagine there will be like 50 cases..

The single option I have found it is to use Class Validator to validate the payload at every case.

I would want to use only typescript types and not third party libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a type that is a union of tuple types that represents the mapping of all the combinations of arguments your function accepts.

For example:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C }

type HandlerArgs =
  | [handler: MyEnum.A, payload: { a: string }]
  | [handler: MyEnum.B, payload: { b: number }]
  | [handler: MyEnum.C, payload: { c: boolean }]
```

The `HandlerArgs` type binds specific payloads with specific enum values.

Now you can write an implementation like this:

```
class Foo {
  async handle([handler, payload]: HandlerArgs) {
    switch(handler) {
      case MyEnum.A: {
        console.log(payload.a) // fine
        break
      }
      case MyEnum.B: {
        console.log(payload.b) // fine
        break
      }
      case MyEnum.C: {
        console.log(payload.c) // fine
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see that the type of `payload` is getting correctly narrowed to the payload type in the arguments tuple that was matched.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3lAggGigIWwYSgF8AoEgFzgAdgoAJAQxABMAbYAJ3Q4HMBnKAF4SUKAB8oAbQAWTNpwBcsRMgB0WKFQZxWAewbMlaBkr7kOASxA9iAXRHipsluw5L4SSKrybteg0ZQAEZKyEGcdg4SMnKu7ipe+NhaOvqGUGgAxkpBurrsTJEkmawMfAIAYnkZDmVwIJlQzvIAFDEunMl+abZKjB1cvHwAlDWionwA7hbkmdItza6jKA7jUJlltB5q6Eara+u6IHz5wKp6PC0p-syqDMP7a0EcwAwA1o-Enxt8WwkQ3j2B3GmSOJ3Y510l2uaVUQQewNEz1eH2BpGBPz+ngB+CBiNBx1OkOh3QMqkyCMRyPen3R4zppFIQA)

---

You could even pull the payload types from the arguments of the functions you plan to pass those payloads to. You would do this by using the `Parameters` type to find the arguments of the functions and and derive that payload types from that.

For example:

```
enum MyEnum { A, B, C }

type HandlerArgs =
  | [handler: MyEnum.A, payload: Parameters<Foo['aHandler']['execute']>[0]]
  | [handler: MyEnum.B, payload: Parameters<Foo['bHandler']['execute']>[0]]
  | [handler: MyEnum.C, payload: Parameters<Foo['cHandler']['execute']>[0]]

class Foo {
  // mock some services this class uses
  declare aHandler: { execute: (payload: { a: string }) => void }
  declare bHandler: { execute: (payload: { b: number }) => void }
  declare cHandler: { execute: (payload: { c: boolean }) => void }

  async handle([handler, payload]: HandlerArgs) {
    switch(handler) {
      case MyEnum.A: {
        this.aHandler.execute(payload)
        break
      }
      case MyEnum.B: {
        this.bHandler.execute(payload)
        break
      }
      case MyEnum.C: {
        this.cHandler.execute(payload)
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here `Parameters<Foo['aHandler']['execute']>[0]` drills into the type of `Foo.aHandler.execute` and finds the parameters of that function, and then uses the first parameter as the payload type.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3lAggGigIWwYSgF8AoEgFzgAdgoAJAQxABMAbYAJ3Q4HMBnKAF4SUKAB8oAbQAWTNpwBcsRMgB0WKFQZxWAewbMlABQYcGEYOU58APADFduyQHIGjFuw7OAui+AAPYABjMCsfAD5JAAZvbxFxKVkPRWUkSFU8TW09A2NTc0tre0cXACN3eS9fZwDg0OAI6Nj4iRk5TyV4NIhVfGwtHX1DKBMzCysOWwcnZyCKzx8-QJCw70iYuJIg1gY+AWmoFHiAemOoCF0ggGsoPl0LW84ANwBLIOABcmkXgW3dgTAfA+8WYwR2HFobnaKTQtRWwCUAAoBjlhmgGEo+OQOC8QDxiABKIThKBPXQvZjEEFg0y0crQjhKWHLepIlFDJlQUpKZClTiE4mk8mU0iiUF-CFQOYMzlw1lQZHZDmHKVKUqOdhMAWCElkilU+K7OAgIJQJLyRFtZIcfpKgzeJTzTjcfhEo6iUR8ADuL3IQWkiPNnjd8Q9Ut2tC6anQTNDYagXx+qih1tUcqsisGBgJcbDpQhDCuuap8fDQNSahwsdLokTfFU9NT6eAmdROZrXILRdLovjQQjFfS+GrNbrqmlTZZGfZ2eLonzwELxd7ol7pFIQA)